# Convert R data frame to time series

Tags: r, xts

Hello I have been trying to use xts to convert a dataframe to time series my understanding is I need to first convert the Date column that is currently set character type to a date type my data set has about 250 rows I was hoping to access the column that contains the date data then run a function to convert char to date. Any advice would be helpful thank you.

```
str(gas)
Classes ‘spec_tbl_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    253 obs. of     
5 variables:
$ Date         : chr  "8/22/2017" "8/23/2017" "8/24/2017" "8/25/2017" ...
$ Google.Close : num  925 927 921 916 914 ...
$ Amazon.Close : num  967 958 952 945 946 ...
$ Google.Return: num  NA 0.0025 -0.00617 -0.00585 -0.00227 ...
$ Amazon.Return: num  NA -0.009205 -0.005793 -0.007549 0.000804 ...
 - attr(*, "spec")=
 .. cols(
 ..   Date = col_character(),
 ..   Google.Close = col_double(),
 ..   Amazon.Close = col_double(),
 ..   Google.Return = col_double(),
 ..   Amazon.Return = col_double()
 .. )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the `as.Date` function.  You will need to specify the format of the dates. In your case, that seems to be `%m/%d/%Y`. You can read about these formats on the help page `?strptime`.

```
 gas$Date = as.Date(gas$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```